# How do you find that $\lim_{n\to\infty} nx(1-x^4)^n$ is equal to $0$ for $x \in (0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

I found this procedure:
for $x \in (0,1) \ \ \lim_{n\to\infty} nx(1-x^4)^n = x \cdot lim_{n\to\infty} n(1-x^4)^n = 0$
But why is it evaluated to $0$? Wouldn't it lead to $0 \cdot \infty$ (as $n$ multiplies $(1-x^4)^n$ , which is equal to $0$ in the interval $(0,1)$)?

Comment: Think of it more as a race between the two functions $n$ and $(1-x^{4})^{n}$. The $n$ term is growing linearly, where as the $(1-x^{4})^{n}$ term is decaying exponentially when $x \in (0,1)$. Exponential decay approaches $0$ 'faster' (for lack of a better word) than linear growth approaches $\infty$. Hence, the limit of the product of the two functions converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "evaluated at zero". Here $x $ is a fixed number between  $0$ and $1$. So it can be "pulled out" from the limit. Also, as $0 <x <1$, we have $0 <1-x^4<1$. Then $\log (1-x^4)<0$, and
$$
n (1-x^4)^n=ne^{n\log (1-x^4)}\to0.
$$
Multiplied by the constant  $x $, it still goes to,zero.